# Plotly: best way to define the Z argument in the create_annotated_heatmap() function

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I'm brand new to Plotly and Dash.  I'm trying to create a heat map that displays the underyling numerical values.

The docs at https://plotly.com/python/heatmaps/ say that it's possible to use the `ff.create_annotated_heatmap()`  function, as follows:

```
import plotly.figure_factory as ff

z = [[.1, .3, .5],
     [1.0, .8, .6],
     [.6, .4, .2]]

x = ['Team A', 'Team B', 'Team C']
y = ['Game Three', 'Game Two', 'Game One']

z_text = [['Win', 'Lose', 'Win'],
          ['Lose', 'Lose', 'Win'],
          ['Win', 'Win', 'Lose']]

fig = ff.create_annotated_heatmap(z, x=x, y=y, annotation_text=z_text, colorscale='Viridis')
fig.show()
```

The first argument, `data`, seems to be a list of lists.

My data looks as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Make':['Ford', 'Ford', 'Ford', 'Buick', 'Buick', 'Buick', 'Mercedes', 'Mercedes', 'Mercedes'],
                          'Score':['88.6', '76.6', '86.2', '79.1', '86.8', '96.4', '97.3', '98.7', '98.5'],
                          'Dimension':['Speed', 'MPG', 'Styling', 'Speed', 'MPG', 'Styling', 'Speed', 'MPG', 'Styling'],
                          'Month':['Apr-19', 'Apr-19', 'Apr-19', 'Apr-19', 'Apr-19', 'Apr-19', 'Apr-19', 'Apr-19', 'Apr-19']})
```

And, my code is as follows:

```
ford_scores = df[(df['Make'].isin(['Ford']))]['Score'].astype(float).tolist()
buick_scores = df[(df['Make'].isin(['Buick']))]['Score'].astype(float).tolist()
mercedes_scores = df[(df['Make'].isin(['Mercedes']))]['Score'].astype(float).tolist()

import plotly.figure_factory as ff
fig = ff.create_annotated_heatmap(
            z=[ford_scores, buick_scores, mercedes_scores],
            x=df['Dimension'].unique().tolist(),
            y=df['Make'].unique().tolist(),
            colorscale=['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green'],
            hoverongaps=False
            )

fig.show()
```

This code works, but it breaks down *spectacularly* when the values in the `Make` column are something other than "Ford", "Buick" or "Mercedes" (or if the number of elements increases or decreases).

As you can see, I'm manually defining the `ford_scores`, `buick_scores` and `mercedes_scores` before passing them to the Z argument in the create_annotated_heatmap() function.

This is hacky.  There has to be a better way!

Is there a way to pass in the '`df`' data frame to the Z argument such that the function "understands" that the Z argument consists of the values in the 'Score' column?  If not, is there another way to pass in the Z argument such that doing so doesn't require advance knowledge of the data and pre-processing the lists? (i.e. so that it's agnostic and flexible as to what's being passed in)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that there is a much better (and less hacky) way!  Courtesy of our friends at Plotly, the solution is as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Make':['Ford', 'Ford', 'Ford', 'Buick', 'Buick', 'Buick', 'Mercedes', 'Mercedes', 'Mercedes'],
                          'Score':['88.6', '76.6', '86.2', '79.1', '86.8', '96.4', '97.3', '98.7', '98.5'],
                          'Dimension':['Speed', 'MPG', 'Styling', 'Speed', 'MPG', 'Styling', 'Speed', 'MPG', 'Styling'],
                          'Month':['Apr-19', 'Apr-19', 'Apr-19', 'Apr-19', 'Apr-19', 'Apr-19', 'Apr-19', 'Apr-19', 'Apr-19']})

df['Score'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Score'])
df = pd.pivot_table(df, values='Score', index='Make', columns=['Dimension'])

import plotly.figure_factory as ff

fig = ff.create_annotated_heatmap(
            z=df.to_numpy(),
            x=df.columns.tolist(),
            y=df.index.tolist(),
            colorscale=['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green'],
            hoverongaps=False
            )

fig.show()
```

Hope this helps someone in the future!